# Is it possible to wget stackoverflow.com/reputation with login credential

Tags: discussion, reputation, login

```
wget -O- "https://stackoverflow.com/reputation"
--14:06:46--  https://stackoverflow.com/reputation
           => `-'
Resolving stackoverflow.com... 64.34.119.12
Connecting to stackoverflow.com|64.34.119.12|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
14:06:47 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I assume credential login is required for https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

So, what is the necessary login setting required for this?

The background story is the idiot (me) who tends to purge unselected answers (even with up votes) on SO, and my curiosity driving me to click button **"Trigger Reputation Recalc"** on https://stackoverflow.com/reputation does ...

So, long story short, since that, close to 2,000 reputation is purged (manage to recover about 1,000 reputation, but still missed the another 1,000)

And want to create a personal backup ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the SO API doesn't support authentication, although [it is scheduled for V2](https://stackapps.com/questions/751/api-v2-musings-what-would-you-like-to-see/753#753).  So the answer to your question is that you have to lower yourself to web-scraping to do this.

But as Jon comments above, you don't need authentication for this: reputation is public information.

If you do want to write cookie-passing web-scraping code, you'll almost certainly find [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) easier than wget, even if you have a reasonable grasp of wget.  Look at [Daniel Stenberg's tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html); section 10 deals with cookies.

Answer (score 5):

SO uses cookies rather than login credentials with each request.  The whole OpenID thing would make it rather hard to provide credentials with each request.  You would need to export your cookies from your browser so you can tell wget to send them along with your request.

Check [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8154/) for a Firefox extension that will extract your cookies.

And [here](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2007/09/15/use-wget-or-curl-to-download-from-rapidshare-premium/) is an example of using cookies with wget and curl - not for SO specifically but it should point you in the right direction.

Alternatively, maybe the [API](http://stackapps.com) might be able to do what you want easier?

Comment: i think i kind of off-topic, will move to meta.stackoverflow.com soon

Comment: Apparently the API supports no kind of authentication, and so can only access information that is visible to everyone.

Comment: couldn't you also, ya know, push a cookie in the post header? or does wget not allow sending a header to the server? (nm, the link says how to do that, duh)

Comment: @Charles Stewart there's a fair amount of information that's visible to everyone: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/your-id-here/reputation  It may do what the OP is looking to do...